# Is there any possibility for the Sanhedrin to reform, the temple to be rebuilt, and sacrifices to continue?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, maseches-sanhedrin

Ever since the destruction of the second temple and the Jewish diaspora, Judaism seems to be somewhat crippled. There's all these commands in the Torah for sacrifices to be carried out in the temple but absent a temple it is impossible to follow the commands.

Is there any reason why the modern day Israelites haven't reconstructed the temple and started performing sacrifices again? Is there any popular demand for this to occur? Similarly, is there anything stopping the Sanhedrin from reforming? Does anyone actually want this to happen?

Comment: (If that's too many questions in one go I can split into two separate questions, just say the word)

Comment: I'm not authoritative, but I would ask about the temple and sanhedrin separately, although the two may be related.

Comment: Yeah, there is popular demand. The stuff you are talking about will happen upon the Messianic redemption. It should be soon

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any reason why the modern day Israelites haven't reconstructed the temple

There is currently a Mosque sitting on the site of the Temple.

> and started performing sacrifices again?

There are a number of prohibiting circumstances such as arguments about the exact description of the priestly garments and lack of genealogical documentation for priests.

> Is there any popular demand for this to occur?

The expectation is that this will be resumed with the advent of the Messiah.

> Similarly, is there anything stopping the Sanhedrin from reforming?

There [is an argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semikhah#Attempts_to_revive_classical_semikhah) going back a few hundred years over whether and how it is possible to re-establish semicha and the Sanhedrin.

> Does anyone actually want this to happen?

We pray at least three times a day that G-d return the services and sacrifices of the Temple in the seventeenth blessing of the [Amidah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah#Structure_of_the_weekday_Amidah).

Comment: This completely ignores people who are trying to get it started today. They exist, even if you don't agree with them. It also ignores the issues of Pikuach Nefesh associated with the Temple Mount.

Comment: @DoubleAA He didn't ask if there are people trying to get it started. He asked why people aren't getting it started. If you have more information you'd like to answer with, there is a button below labeled "Add Another Answer". You can click on that and discuss the Temple Institute and any other additional relevant facts that you think may be pertinent to the question.

Comment: Actually, he did ask "Is there any popular demand for this to occur?"

Comment: @DoubleAA I wrote according to the shitah of the Ramba"m and according to what seems to me to be what people generally expect. Unless you have a poll on popular demand, I don't think you can say that I lied as much as that I would have been more accurate to say, "My experience has been..." Unless you are trying to say that the Temple Institute's position is the popular one?

Comment: Just answer the question "Is there any popular demand for this to occur?" with the truth: there is. If you want to say that in your experience that's a minority of people thats fine (though most people probably don't know what theyre talking about in terms of Kodshim and Taharot). In addition sourcing your various claims would improve this post in general. Note the Rambams position is not so clear (he allows מקריבין אע״פ שאין בית and he admits that the sequence of events in the eschaton is not known definitively). Its well known a bunch of Tosafists moved to Israel to try to restart Korbanot.